# Spring Boot Application on EC2 shutting down automatically after sometime

Tags: java, java-8, cloud, aws-sdk

Need help to understand why does the spring boot I have deployed on EC2 instance keeps on shutting down after sometime on it's own. It is suppose to work as a server for my application.

Comment: Any set of logs before the shutdown ??

Comment: Share enough details to explain your problem with logs, configs, snapshots, etc.

Comment: Closed by remote host! Nothing else is coming.

Comment: Have you tried running your application locally before deploying on EC2?

Comment: yes It works like charm.

Comment: Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65002561/4039698) answer here. The java process might be stopping because of the `SIGHUP` call.